# What is the period of the harmonic oscillator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to find the elapsed time $T$ (or transit time) over one cycle of the harmonic oscillator

$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2x=0.$$

I worked this out to be
\begin{align}
  T
  &= \int_{R}^{-R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{-y} 
  + \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y}\\
  &= \int_{R}^{-R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{-\sqrt{R^2-\omega^2x^2}} 
  + \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{R^2-\omega^2x^2}}\\ 
  &= -\frac{1}{\omega} \int_{R}^{-R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{D^2-x^2}} 
  + \frac{1}{\omega} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{D^2-x^2}}
\end{align}

where $D=R/\omega$.

When I evaluate the definite integral, I get $T=4\arcsin(\omega)/\omega $, which makes no sense to me because $\arcsin(\omega)$ bounds $\omega$ at unity. Since $\omega$ is the angular frequency, the answer should be $T=2\pi/\omega$.

Could someone point out where I went so wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup is entirely correct, but your evaluation of the integral is not. The primitive of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{D^2 -x^2}}$ is $\text{arctan} \frac{x}{\sqrt{D^2 -x^2}}$; taking the appropriate limits yields the desired factor $\pi$, for each integral.

**Edit:** As @MichaelSeifert rightly pointed out, the integral can also be expressed in terms of $\text{arcsin}$, since
\begin{equation}
\text{arctan} \frac{x}{\sqrt{D^2 -x^2}} = \text{arcsin} \frac{x}{D}.
\end{equation}
As $\text{arcsin} 1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$, you get the requested answer.

Comment: Oh, okay. This solves my problem. I realize now how long it has been since Calculus II :)

Comment: The integral isn't wrong: $\arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{D^2 - x^2}} = \arcsin (x/D)$.  Draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $D$ and opposite side $x$ to see this.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you integrate once to find the first integral 
$$
E(x,y)=\frac12(y^2+ω^2x^2)
$$
and that the points of largest amplitude are $(x,y)=(\pm R,0)$. But then the constant is
$$
E=\frac12ω^2R^2
$$
and thus the equation for $y$ is
$$
y=\pmω\sqrt{R^2-x^2}
$$

Now use the substitution $x=R\sin u$ to solve the resulting integral for the half-period,
$$
\frac T2=\int_{-R}^R\frac{dx}y=\frac1ω\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}du=\frac{\pi}{ω}
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the function $E(x,y)$?

Comment: It is constant on $E(x,\dot{x})$.